# Error: Could not create index on view "dbo.DataEx". The view contains a self join on "dbo.Classifier"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is a "self join" correct and full definition? As I understand self join is something like  `...FROM Role r1 INNER JOIN Role r2 ON r1.ID = r2.ParenteRoleId`

But where the "self join" is in this code: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7d058/1

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Classifier
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Data
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ClassifierID1 int  NOT NULL,
    ClassifierID2 int  NOT NULL
)

GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.DataEx WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT d.ID, c1.Name as ClassifierName1, c2.Name as ClassifierName2
FROM dbo.Data d
    INNER JOIN dbo.Classifier c1 ON d.ClassifierID1=c1.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Classifier c2 ON d.ClassifierID2=c2.ID

GO 


SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [dbo$DataEx$PK] ON dbo.DataEx 
(
    [ID]
)

GO
```

This code throws an error:

```
Cannot create index on view "testdb.dbo.DataEx". The view contains a self join on "testdb.dbo.Classifier".
```

I also have tried to avoid this error using `FROM dbo.Data d,   dbo.Classifier c1,  dbo.Classifier c2 WHERE d.ClassifierID1=c1.ID AND d.ClassifierID2=c2.ID` but this doesn't help.

As I understand I can't use the same table twice in Indexed Views and I can't do anything with that, but at least I could learn some terminology ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-join is, simply, any join which produces a result set which contains the same table more than once.

It doesn't matter whether the particular join conditions used to introduce each instance of the table mention the other instances of the same table.

---

(And the bad news, for the meta-question, is that if you're encountering this problem now, it's unlikely that there's a reformulation of your view's query such that it will be indexable)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the msdn document 'Create Indexed Views' [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)

Here, it's specified that

The SELECT statement in the view definition must not contain Transact-SQL elements like Self-joins etc